# Cambiar color de flecha de popover de bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap

quiero saber como puedo cambiar el color de las flechas de los popover de bootstrap. Tengo el css de bootstrap linkeado.

Debo modificar el css local o el de bootstrap?

Comment: Compartí un poco el código de lo que fuiste haciendo, no se te puede ayudar así.

Comment: No deberías tocar nunca las clases del framework a menos que sea absolutamente imprescindible o tengas clarísimo que tu cambio es tan definitivo como aplicable en cualquier supuesto de tu site. En mi opinión sería mejor que creases una clase propia en tu css y la aplicases allí donde hiciera falta por si en el futuro bien, quisieras dar marcha atrás o bien aplicar otro estilo a este mismo elemento y que convivan ambos. Por ejemplo para acciones A esa flecha será verde, para acciones B será roja.

Answer (score 0):

Es mejor que hagas una modificacion a tu css local, que este por encima de la referencia a bootstrap.

```
.popover-header{
  /// tus cambios en la cabecera del popover
 }

.popover-body{
  /// tus cambios en el cuerpo del popover
 }

 popover > .arrow{
  /// tus en la flecha del popover
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilice este `CSS` cambiando el color del borde derecho del elemento [Pseudo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements):

```
.popover.right .arrow:after {
  border-right-color: red;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### Mira a quí un [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5Kree/) para que veas el funcionamiento del mismo.

---

Otro pequeño ejemplo:

Usando un `popover` estándar en Bootstrap 3:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="Este es el mensaje">
  Popover on right
</button>
```

Puede agregar el siguiente css a sus reglas personalizadas:

```
.popover {
  background-color: red; /*sustituye 'rojo' con tu color de elección*/
  border-color: red;
}
.popover.right>.arrow:after {
  border-right-color: red;
}
.popover-content {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

La mejor opción es seleccionar cada caso y modificarlo:

```
.bs-popover-top > .popover-arrow::after{
    border-top-color: #27f !important;
}

.bs-popover-bottom > .popover-arrow::after{
    border-bottom-color: #27f !important;
}

.bs-popover-start > .popover-arrow::after{
    border-left-color: #27f !important;
}

.bs-popover-end > .popover-arrow::after{
    border-right-color: #27f !important;
}
```

Esta solución solo la he comprobado para Bootstrap 5. Espero que te sirva.